# The empty space on the chart xaxis

Tags: highcharts

If the distance between two points on the xaxis of the biggest (on the example of the `[1,110116],[40,30166]`), then the graph on the left and on the right you'll see an empty place. How to avoid it?

[jsfiddle.net/67U3w/](http://jsfiddle.net/67U3w/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try altering 'minPadding'. This isn't an exact science, just trial and error.

`xAxis: {
  minPadding: -.011
 }`

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67U3w/1/

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it is not universal. Found the solution - add zeros at blank point.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pointRange: 1`, to prevent that behavior, see: http://jsfiddle.net/67U3w/2/